# error while executing hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I run hive query getting below error.

ERROR:SQL execution failed with exception :: 
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. 
Application application_1568799867343_133452 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1568799867343_133452_000002 exited with  exitCode: 255

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Share hive version, tez version and queries to you tried. Paste complete logs.

Comment: And *"complete logs"* means what you will get running `yarn application -status application_1568799867343_133452` then `yarn logs -applicationId application_1568799867343_133452`